# How do I force an object to overlap in PySide?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to create a search feature in my pyside program that shows results based on a user input. Currently, I have a QLineEdit setup for the user to make an entry. When the user enters a match, the results should appear in the QLineEdit as it will expand. The program is divided into two frames: A top frame (where the search bar is located) and a content frame which shows the raw content.

My issue is that when I am trying to expand the QLineEdit, it doesn't allow itself to overlap into the content frame and becomes hidden. Here's an image of what I would like to happen.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

I understand that I have horizontal policies setup on both frames with a "No-frame" frame shape, would this have an impact on the output?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I sincerely hope you're not trying to add the results *inside* the QLineEdit while the user is typing, because that seems a terrible way to show search results.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit hard to understand for me. I got a feeling you are trying to make something similar to auto-completion or drop-down features...  If so could you please explain how it should differ from QCompleter or QComboBox functions...

Comment: @musicamante Hi, I realised that was silly early on, I want a second box to appear right beneath it.

Comment: @StarterKit A dropdown box would be the best way to describe it. I have a directory that contains the names of all the players in a sports league, when a user enters a name it will search the directory for all the players that contain that string and return them in a dropdown box for it to be chosen

Comment: @AwaisShah then you should set a [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) on the line edit.

Comment: Yes, QCompleter might be an option. But I would propose to create a custom model based on QAbstractTableModel or QAbstractListModel and then use QComboBox with it. Can't make a clear example becasue I still have not clear enough understanding of what you want as a result.